# Was "Calling all Cachebusters" ....now - "Can I delay ajax call until div is empty?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slideshow

I had started a gnarly js slideshow question thinking I had a cache issue related to my ajax function, etc., but I think I've isolated this issue.  Here's the synopsis, then code, then question.

1. the main page has a set of links (categories) which drive the MYSQL lookup.
2. the main page has an image container div (position: relative) which is empty.
3. I do an ajax call which returns a set of image source urls from MYSQL.
4. I create individual img elements (position: absolute) and append them to the main imagediv.  The imgs default to opacity: 0 via CSS;
5. I set the first image to opacity: 1 via CSS.
6. If there are more than one image I show the prev/next buttons.
7. Next/previous work by adding/removing the opacity and selected class.  If I'm on the last child I switch to the first, and vice versa.  This crossfade works beautifully.

Now the fun begins.  Each time I select a different category link I start by emptying the imagediv of the prior content so it can be repopulated with new results.  That seems to work as well.....most of the time.

What I've noticed is that ***after switching back/forth between categories*** the mechanism "breaks" - what I mean is the next/prev don't advance the image.  However, ***if I select that same category again***, basically "refreshing" it, it starts working again!  Sometimes it takes 4-5 different category selections to break it, but it always fails at some point.  Also, sometimes when I click on the category link I get a blank screen (no first image opaque)....even though I know there is one.

I'm wondering if perhaps the ajax call and success functions are completing prior to the imagediv being emptied, and that the empty method ***actually completes after*** the ajax function?

Any thoughts on how I could hold off the ajax function until I can prove the imagediv is empty?  Pseudocode:  "if imagediv is not empty, empty it *and don't proceed until it is*"...

```
$(".nav-link").click(function() {

       var category = $(this).attr("data-categoryid");  //link which sets the category

        //before anything happens, clear out the prior imagediv
       $("#imagediv").empty(); 

       //getImageData accesses MYSQL and returns JSON encoded list of image urls, captions and titles
       //for the specified category typeid  - each category has it's own triggering link on the main page
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "actions.php?action=getImageData&?cachebuster=" + new Date().getTime() + "",  //tried to use a cache buster! didn't work.
            data: "categoryid= " + category,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(result) {

                for (i=0; i< result.length; i++) {

                    var $img = $( "<img class='img-fluid main-image myImage mx-auto d-block' src='" + result[i]["url"] + "' >");

                    //create the img elements and append to the imagediv container
                    $("#imagediv").append($img);

                }   

                //set the first image to opaque...all others default to opacity=0 via css
                $("#imagediv img").eq(0).addClass("opaque selected");


                //if there's only one image url in the results, hide the next/previous buttons
                if (result.length > 1) {$("#centerdiv").show();} else {$("#centerdiv").hide();}

            },  cache: false,

        }); 

        $("#next").click(function(){

            var $next = $('.myImage.selected').removeClass('selected opaque').next('.myImage');
            if ($next.length) {
            $next.addClass('selected opaque'); 
            }
            else {
                $(".myImage:first").addClass('selected opaque');
            }

        });

        $("#previous").click(function(){

            var $prev = $('.myImage.selected').removeClass('selected opaque').prev('.myImage');
            if ($prev.length) {
            $prev.addClass('selected opaque'); 
            }
            else {
                $(".myImage:last").addClass('selected opaque');
            }       

        });    

    });
```

Thanks for putting up with this long post (and the prior one).  I can't put this on a fiddle due to the structure of multiple files, use of MYSQL, my own image files in a directory, etc....all too complicated.

Comment: every time `$(".nav-link").click(function() {` is called, you ADD another `$("#next").click(function(){` and `$("#previous").click(function(){` ... you need to remove the existing click handlers before adding new ones

Comment: Jaromanda, muy perfect response.  And, it explains all kinds of wild things I was experiencing before...superimposed images, etc.  I've been banging my head on this for three days now and the solution took one minute to implement!  I added two lines of code added to "off" the click handlers before the ajax call and it works flawlessly. I'd buy you a beer or ten if I could.

Comment: With the temperature outside hitting 40+C already, a beer or ten would be welcome :p